# which is write neural network prediction code

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, prediction

predict.csv :

```
AlAin,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5,Y6,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,d
1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
```

the codes of the predictive part of the artificial neural network:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    predictdataset=pd.read_csv('predict.csv')
    y_predict=(sess.run(tf.argmax(y4.eval(feed_dict={x:[predictdataset]}),1)))
    print(y_predict)
```

I get a 'KeyError: 0' error.

previous codes for training and testing

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,15]) 
    y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 1])

```
layer_1=128
layer_2=64
layer_3=32
layer_out=1

weight_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([15, layer_1], stddev=0.1))
bias_1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[layer_1]))
weight_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([layer_1, layer_2], stddev=0.1))
bias_2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[layer_2]))
weight_3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([layer_2, layer_3], stddev=0.1))
bias_3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[layer_3]))

weight_4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([layer_3, layer_out], stddev=0.1))
bias_4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[layer_out]))

y1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,weight_1)+bias_1)
y2=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y1,weight_2)+bias_2)
y3=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(y2,weight_3)+bias_3)
logits=tf.matmul(y3,weight_4)+bias_4

y4=tf.nn.softmax(logits)

xent = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xent)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y4, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)) # Başarı oranı

optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001). minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few very basic issues I see. You should probably go through some TensorFlow tutorials explaining its graph computation model:

- You cannot feed a panda DataFrame as a value of a tensor, as you do in `y4.eval(feed_dict={x:[predictdataset]})`
- You should not use a list for feed values, as you do in `y4.eval(feed_dict={x:[predictdataset]})`
- TensorFlow operations generally take symbolic tensors. It is ok to pass parameters that can be converted to tensors, but in your example it almost defeats the purpose of TensorFlow. You are evaluating a tensor just to pass it to `tf.argmax` in `tf.argmax(y4.eval(feed_dict={x:[predictdataset]}),1))`. You should just pass `y4` directly.

Comment: okey, i can try "y4.eval(feed-dict={x:[predictdataset]})" @iga

Comment: See my second point above - remove []. If you are still having issues, please provide complete self contained code and a full stack trace of the error.